# How to invalidate httpcache in one action?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, cache-control

I have simply action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $news = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:News')->findBy(array('main' => 1));
    $response = $this->render('index.html.twig', array('news' => $news));

    $response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);
    $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);

    return $response;
}
```

It works well, the site is cached, but I would like to change it in the admin panel in module News, invalidate this cache and let all users see the changes.

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/save-news", name="admin_save_news")
 */
public function saveNewsAction(Request $request)
{
    //...
    $em->persist($news);
    $em->flush();
    //how to invalidate here?
    //...
}
```

I tried:

```
protected function invalidateCache($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PURGE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $status == 200;
}
```

$url = 'http://example.com/';

But it doesn't work and in addition is strange... It must be a nicer way